# Web Application not working in Safari

Tags: .net

We have developed a web application in .NET framework 3.5. Presently our application is compatible with IE and firefox browsers, but we are not able to browse the application in Safari.
When we browse the application using Safari , page is getting loaded as blank.

Please advice how to make the application compatible with Safari.

Comment: By "loaded as blank" do you mean it displays nothing or that there simply is nothing transmitted to the browser (i.e. viewing the source of the page on the browser also shows an empty screen)?

Comment: does the web inspector console show any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to update the browserCaps section of your Machine.config file? ASP.NET will send the client a "simple" version of the page if it doesn't recognize the browser.

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <browserCaps>
    ...
            <!-- AppleWebKit Based Browsers (Safari...) //-->
           <case match="AppleWebKit/(?'version'(?'major'\d?)(?'minor'\d{2})(?'letters'\w*)?)">
               browser=AppleWebKit
               version=${version}
               majorversion=0${major}
               minorversion=0.${minor}
               frames=true
               tables=true
               cookies=true
               javascript=true
               javaapplets=true
               ecmascriptversion=1.5
               w3cdomversion=1.0
               css1=true
               css2=true
               xml=true
               tagwriter=System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter
           <case match="AppleWebKit/(?'version'(?'major'\d)(?'minor'\d+)(?'letters'\w*))(.* )?(?'type'[^/\d]*)/.*( |$)">
               type=${type}
           </case>
           </case>
            ...
    </browserCaps>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

Source: http://slingfive.com/pages/code/browserCaps/